# If else statement that checks whether the URL entered by the user begins with certain characters in Windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, url

Hi everyone: I am new to batch scripts, and what I want to do right now is to create a batch script that checks if a URL entered by the user begins with certain characters. For example, here is a valid URL:

```
https://123@mysite.com/yourfolder/folder
```

What I want to do is to let the script check to see if the entered URL contains: `https://123@mysite.com/`, if not, then it will output an error message. I've tried a few if else combinations, but all failed. Could you spare me some thoughts? Thanks.

Here is what I have tried:

```
if %url%==%url:https://123@mysite.com/=% (
       echo valid URL 
       else (
        invalid URL)
    )
```

Comment: So where is the code, you'd like us to assist you with? You should at least, have an input prompt, and a failing check of the input content! You cannot expect us to just write it all for you. Also, would it not make more sense to preset the `https://123@mysite.com/` part, and just request the `yourfolder/folder` as input?

Comment: Your question is lacking in detail. Please add examples of the code you have tried so far, and comprehensively detail the usage situation. IE, your example shows 'a' valid Url, Suggesting, but not explicitly stating there may be a variety of Valid Urls.

Comment: @Compo, our users would usually just paste the URL to the prompt, so it would complicate them if I ask them to just paste the last part of the URL, hope this answers your question.

Comment: @T3RR0R, I've just included code in my original question, thanks for taking time to look at my question.

Comment: You should first of all use the case insensitive comparison, in addition you should parenthesise the command correctly, and not miss an essential `echo` command, i.e. `if /i "%url%" == "%url:https://123@mysite.com/=%" (echo valid URL) else echo invalid URL` or if several `else` commands are to follow, `if /i "%url%" == "%url:https://123@mysite.com/=%" (echo valid URL) else (echo invalid URL)` Although for the purpose of this exercise `%url://123@mysite.com/=% should suffice.`

Comment: @Compo, your code works perfectly, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Compo, one additional question: how do you express wildcard in a batch script? In other languages, we would just use an asterisk, but does that work in batch scripts? I've tried to use asterisks in batch scripts, and that didn't seem to work, thanks.

Comment: It depends upon the context @user1452008, you'd need to provide more information.

Comment: Type `if /?` and learn the correct `if`/`else` syntax…

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues with your parenthesized code blocks, but I feel this might be a little simpler.

```
echo %url% | findstr /IRC:"https://123@mysite.com/"
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
    echo Valid URL
) else (
    echo Invalid URL
)
```

Note how I also rectified the code blocks you had incorrect.
The syntax in a straight line is:

```
if "something"=="something" (do something) else ( do something else)
```

So if we place those in indented format, the parenthesis must still conform.

```
if "something"=="something" (
      do something
    ) else (
      do something else
   )
```

Comment: thanks for correcting my codeblock in the original answer, and thanks for providing your solution, have a good day.